# How to embed a Reactive Value in a matrix in the UI section of R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In the below MWE code, I'm trying to insert a reactive value "periods" (generated from the slider input and as defined in the Server section) into the first row and first column of a user-input matrix that appears in the UI section. As you can see below, current setting for that first row/column of matrix is "1". I'd like it to instead be the same value as in "periods", and vary reactively with changes in periods effected by the user moving the slider at the top.

I'm sure this requires some proficiency with Reactivity/observeEvent that I don't yet have. I have fooled with these parameters to no avail.

Also see images below to better explain.

```
library(shiny) 
library(shinyMatrix)

ui <- fluidPage(style = "margin-top:10px;",
    column(3, 
        fluidRow(
             sliderInput("periods", "Nbr of periods (X):",min = 1, max = 120, value = 60)),
      
        fluidRow(
            
            matrixInput(
              "vector_input",
              label = "Generate matrix:",
              value = matrix(c(1, # << this 1 value needs to be reactive input$periods value
                               0.2), 
                         1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("Y", "Z"))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric"),
            
            textOutput("selected_var") 
    )),
    column(9,))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$selected_var <- renderText({paste("Number of periods: ", input$periods)})
 
  vals <- reactiveValues()
  observe({vals$periods <- input$periods})
  
  vector_input  <-  reactive(input$vector_input)
 
} # close server

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is what appears when running the code as drafted and what I am trying to do. In the second image I show the user changing the periods input from 60 to 20, and how I would like the 1st row in column Y of the matrix to reflect that change:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `updateMatrixInput` function gives you a simple solution.  Replace your current server function with

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$selected_var <- renderText({paste("Number of periods: ", input$periods)})
  
  observeEvent(input$periods, {
    updateMatrixInput(session, "vector_input", value=matrix(c(input$periods, 0.2), 1, 2))
  })
}
```

And I believe you get the functionality you want.  Note the addition of the `session` parameter to the definition of the `server` function.

Comment: Thank you, works great Limey! I am encouraged by Stack Overflow and people like you who are so willing to help.

Comment: Quick question Limey: I added the 2 following lines of code to create a global variable for testing purposes -- periods <-  reactive(input$periods), and 
  observeEvent(periods(), {periods.R <<- unique(periods())}). I can then access periods.R from other R programs. I'm trying to do the same for updateMatrixInput. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Forget it! I just figured it out. I added to the server section vector_input   <-  reactive(input$vector_input), and observeEvent(vector_input(), {vector_input.R <<- unique(vector_input())}). So now I have global variable vector_input.R

Comment: You could put your global assignments in the same `observeEvent` as the call to `updateMatrixInput` and save yourself a few lines of code.  Also, look at `reactiveValues` rather than `reactive`-and-`observe`.  I think that would be helpful...